# Bootstrap CSS Ignore Style

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with a bootstrap 2.3 template and running into an issue with some styling.

I have a table on my page and I am defining the columns to be specific widths using the `class=span4`.

My issue is that in the css of this template, there is this style:

```
.row [class*="span"] {
    padding: 0;
}
```

When I use the span tag on the table, its removing all the padding from it. I am unable to remove  the css from the main style sheet as its used for other things within the site.

Is there a way I can ignore that for the table I am working on or come up with another style that reverts it back to what it should be on the page I am working on?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add a special class to override for the spans in those rows

```
<tr class="row">
<td><span class="special-span"></span></td>
</tr>
```

and then in your css

```
.row .special-span{
padding: 10px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the !important rule.

```
.row [class*="span"] {
    padding: 0!important;
}
```

Other things to consider:

1. Make sure you include your styles after bootstrap.css and bootstrap-theme.css
2. Make your style more specific than the style you are trying to override.